# Angular use Json for blog posting vs BBDD

Tags: json, angular, parsing, angular7, jsonparser

I'm doing an app with angular since it's easy for me to make it work as a progressive web app, etc. In my app I have a blog section.

The problem is that I need to load a json files dynamically because I'm using it to make new post pages as entry blogs.

I need to know if i can create something like a folder named json and throw all my json files with the content of each post, keeping the angular parsing the folder and looking for new jsons while it's in run time. Or i must use a backend with some mongo or mysql bbdd?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use backend to implement.
Try to receive the service response in JSON array as below:

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "author": "Chinua Achebe",
      "content": "abc"
    },
    {
      "author": "Hans Christian Andersen",
       "content": "def"
    }
  ]
}
```

Just iterate over the posts array to display your posts

Comment: I know I can use back end option, but that is not what I'm asking for. I can't use the json way and avoid create a back end for this simply task?

Comment: tasks are simple , it doesn't implies that you can replace backend work using frontend. You are talking about accessing a dynamic filesystem which you need to to from backend.

Comment: True, but I don't want any kind of behavior in my back end, I just want to know if there's any way to retrieve these files and have them in the front end when the app is loading. So can't I just have my json files on a folder in my front end and just get them when I want them? All post data is static, it never changes. When I add a new json file to the json folder and the client visits the blog section, the front end only would need to check for new json files and do whatever it has to.

Comment: If you can update the json in file every time then its possible . But if you add new files it won't work.

Comment: That is because angular can't access to the file system, true?

Comment: Yes Angular or scripts from browser don't allow to access the file system.